# Android Translate animation different behavior on different devices why?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-animation, translate-animation

I am using this animation to translate an activity from right to left but I observe an issue.

It works fine on a **Samsung S5** but on **Samsung S4** the animation is very fast and you can see almost no animation.

Both have same duration time 300ms.

**right_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <translate 
            android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
            android:toXDelta="0" 
            android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

**left_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0" 
            android:toXDelta="-100%p" 
            android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Animation also works fine on Android emulators.

Answer (score 0):

You have two root tags in your XML which is wrong. The correct way is to have one `<set>` containing two `<translate>` animations.

**Corrected code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <translate 
            android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
            android:toXDelta="0" 
            android:duration="300"/>
    <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0" 
            android:toXDelta="-100%p" 
            android:duration="300"/>
 </set>
```

Update your question after fixing this issue if the strange behavior on different Samsung devices still occurs.